# CLI app on Node.js How to pass the option value as an argument for the Shell command via child_process

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, node-commander

How to pass the value of the --url option as an argument for the Wget command

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const commander = require('commander');
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const program = new commander.Command();

program
  .option('-u, --url <value>', 'Website address');

program.parse(process.argv);

const options = program.opts();

if (options.url) {
        exec("wget ${options.url}", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
                return;
            }
            if (stderr) {
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        });
}
```

Output:

```
node app.js --url ff99cc.art
error: Command failed: wget ${options.url}
/bin/bash: line 1: ${options.url}: bad substitution
```

It is necessary that the --url value is passed as an argument for wget. So that when you execute the node command app.js --url example.com,she was doing wget example.com.

**Solved** Thanks spyrospal and ibrahim tanyalcin
The issue is how you use string interpolation to format the wget command. As mentioned here should be with backtick (`) characters instead of double quotes:

```
exec(`wget ${options.url}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
```

Comment: The string is not computed, use backticks: `wget ${options.url}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is how you use string interpolation to format the `wget` command.
As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should be with backtick (`) characters instead of double quotes:

```
exec(`wget ${options.url}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
```